# VBA INPUT BOX - EXCEL REQUESTS IINFORMATION UPON SPREADSHEET BEING OPENED

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an excel spreadsheet (route book),[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQBAm.png) see attached.
I require excel to request information via a popup input box upon the spreadsheet being opened, which will reflect on b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2 respectively, once all information is filled in then a2 becomes available(this can be done via formula) and then should move on to the next line.
So basically every time a user opens the spreadsheet, excel requests information via a pop up screen, once this information is filled in the order number becomes available the cycle starts again on a new line.
Something like below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szRgp.png)

Then once this is completed then automatically another pop up, until all information is captured and order number becomes available.
I cannot get the pop ups  to follow up one after the other until the end

```
Sub inputbox1()
Dim adddata As Range
Dim addinput As String
Set adddata = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
addinput = InputBox("Enter date here", "Date")
If addinput = Empty Then Exit Sub
adddata.Value = addinput
End Sub
Sub inputbox2()
Dim adddata As Range
Dim addinput As String
Set adddata = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
addinput = InputBox("Enter Transporter here", "Transporter")
If addinput = Empty Then Exit Sub
adddata.Value = addinput
End Sub
```

Comment: why would you have to close and open that workbook again and again instead of having it process as many order numbers output as the user needs?

Comment: There is no question in this question.

Comment: its not necessary to close and open the workbook, but my aim is to get the user to complete the required information first before getting an order number and  prevent any duplication of order numbers between users.